# The order of existence of the identity element in the axiom of identity

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $X=(X, \cdot)$ be a semigroup, which satisfies $\forall a,b,c\in X$, $(a\cdot b)\cdot c = a\cdot (b\cdot c)$.

In the definition of monoids, the axiom of identity is (a) below. What happens if you replace the axiom with (b)?

- (a) $\exists e\in X$, $\forall a\in X$, $ae=ea=a$.
- (b) $\forall a\in X$, $\exists e\in X$, $ae=ea=a$.

I'm considering an example of (b).

Let $G=\{e, a\}$, $G'=\{e',a'\}$ be copies of a group of order 2 ($e\in G$, $e'\in G'$ are identities) and $X = G\sqcup G'$.
And define the operation of a element of $G$ and a element of $G'$ to be $e$.
Does $X$ hold (b)?

Comment: It seems that both (a) and (b) hold for your example; but other semigroup axioms fail (such as associativity).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of an associative law for which (b) holds but (a) doesn't is where $X = \mathbf{R}$ and $a \cdot b = \max(a,b)$.